# How TO DECLARE GLOBAL Variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I had coded value which was used in many `stored procedures`, so to create a **global variable** (at database level) and use that in all the `stored procedure` , 
if the changes again comes then only need to change the value of that variable will impact in all the logic of Stored Procedure.
by global variable i mean : @@Error,@@ROWCOUNT or etc.

please suggest if any other way around.

Comment: There is no way to declare global variable in sql server

Comment: What are you trying to do? "Global variables" have no meaning for a database. You can store configuration but it would be *very* weird if the behavior of a stored procedure changed automagically whenever a configuration changed. It's better to pass such configuration as parameters

Comment: Even if you think the opposite - you do not need any global variables. They are evil, they could kill you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a *table* and store values there. Then any SP needing the value can query that table. I'd normally recommend fixed to one row and multiple columns (so that each column, which represents a "global variable" can have an appropriate data type).

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Globals (
   X char(1) not null,
   GlobalVar1 varchar(250) not null,
   GlobalVar2 int not null,
   constraint PK_Globals PRIMARY KEY (X),
   constraint CK_Globals_Single CHECK (X='X')
)
```

And then insert the row:

```
INSERT INTO Globals (X,GlobalVar1,GlobalVar2)
VALUES ('X','someone@example.com',32)
```

And then update it thereafter. You can then either read specific column values into a local variable in the stored procedure, or just join to this table, depending on what feels most appropriate.

Comment: Or use extender properties. Depends on what the OP wants to do - it would be very weird if a stored procedure's behavior changed automagically. Better use stored procedure parameters to pass such configuration, no matter where it's stored

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I've used this previously for "config" style data - where we do need a few magic numbers or values that more than one stored proc needs to care about. It's not the only option but it can work quite well for that sort of data, where maybe it needs to be changed a few times a year.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever how you have done this, can you please share. , we  have the same situation where changed occurred in a year.